# How to use userInfo of LocalNotification for iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I want to create ingame pause, so I register **`local notification`** to notify user when it's ended.

But there are different purposes for **`local notification`** that I use.

So I used **`userInfo`** to mark a notification that responsible for pause.

```
    private void ScheduleNotification(DateTime date, string message)
    {
#if UNITY_IOS
        LocalNotification not = new LocalNotification();
        not.applicationIconBadgeNumber = NotificationServices.localNotificationCount + 1;
        not.alertBody = message;
        not.fireDate = date;
        not.userInfo["pause"] = 0;
        NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification(not);
#endif
    }
```

But I don't know how to get **`LocalNotification`** that was activated, how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to `LocalNotification` for this?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-set-local-alerts-using-uilocalnotification and http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Comment: You should read the Unity Documentation-> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification.html

Comment: because pause can be too long and user can close the app, so I have to notify him that pause is ended in he can play again

Comment: OK that makes sense.

Comment: ok i got it, i can get list of received notification